# Benefits of XMPP over Webscokets for Android Chat App

Tags: android, websocket, xmpp

I am in the process of building an Android chat application with image sharing and came across two contenders for it's implementation, XMPP and Webscokets. I have found several tutorials for creating an Android chat application with Websockets and none for using XMPP, even though Whatsapp uses XMPP. I would go with Websockets but many cite that using websockets will kill your phones battery quickly.

Before going with either one, what are the benefits of using either Websockets or XMPP for an Android chat application?